# Understanding Python Dictionary construction statement with loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Hello I not new to Python but I am in the habit of reading long code rather than short, smarter code. Could anyone help me understanding the format of data this statement is going to produce? Is it a `dict` of `dict`?

`accounts = [dict(Name="Account%d" % idx) for idx in xrange(5)]`

Could you explain how it is? Like in Json rep? I would like to see it in pictorial represenataion and if you could explain the code itself thanks

Comment: Just try printing it in Python2, outputs a list of dictionaries `[{'Name': 'Account0'}, {'Name': 'Account1'}, {'Name': 'Account2'}, {'Name': 'Account3'}, {'Name': 'Account4'}]`

Comment: One of the nice things about Python is its robust REPL, where you can try short code snippets at any time and see what they do. Especially if they're as self-contained as this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a list of dicts, built using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Comment: @Solly `print accounts`

Comment: @Solly What do you mean by pictorial? The statement produces a list of dictionaries of the form `{"Name": "Account0"}, ....{"Name": "Account4}` using list comprehension. You should read about it, is a really neat feature of the language.